# FIWARE Orion Context Broker subscription not pushing to accumulator-server

Tags: docker, fiware, fiware-orion

I've been stuck here for a day... I'm not sure if its an Orion problem or a docker problem.
I'm playing around with Orion and a few other FIWARE components in docker-compose. I followed the [1](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/1.15.0/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#subscriptions) instruction to try the subscription but it doesn't work, as the accumulator-server doesn't receive any update notifications.

I've checked several similar questions on StackOverflow, and here are 3 possible issues that I found and my situations.

1. Might be a connection issue due to the truth that Orion is running docker container on MacOS and trying to reach external acc-server.
   My situation: According to[2](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds), I've tried to change the url filed in subscription request from "http://localhost:1028/accumulate" to "http://host.docker.internal:1028/accumulate". It still doesn't work. I use a bridge network in my docker-compose.yml. I'm new to docker and I'm not sure what other settings do I need to specify in order to reach server on the localhost from a container.
2. Something wrong with OCB or subscription.
   My situation: Once I POST the subscription (I put subsciption in the appendix below. Orion is supposed to send notification to acc-server once I update the value of a self-defined dummy sensor), there's an HTTP 201 response that looks correct. The log in Orion looks like below:

`orion_1        | INFO@06:48:35  connectionOperations.cpp[375]: Database Operation Successful (insert: { _id: ObjectId('5e2fd943bcf1cf1869212cfe'), expiration: 1893506400, reference: "http://host.docker.internal:1028/accumulate", custom: false, throttling: 1, servicePath: "/#", description: "A subscription to notify clampPressure change", status: "active", entities: [ { id: "RoboticArm", isPattern: "false", type: "multiSensor", isTypePattern: false } ], attrs: [ "clampPressure" ], metadata: [], blacklist: false, onlyChanged: false, conditions: [ "clampPressure" ], expression: { q: "", mq: "", geometry: "", coords: "", georel: "" }, format: "normalized" })`

If I check GET v2/subsciptions. All the subscriptions are there showing "active". While when I update the entity, the notification never reaches the acc-server. And if I check the logs of Orion, there's only logs about updating entity. There's nothing related to subscription status...Only the above one when first POST subscription. It seems like the Orion doesn't operate the subscription.

3. Issue with accumulator-server.py
   My situation: I started it as [2](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds), it looks fine. It just never receives anything from orion. If I try to post something through host, it works fine. I think the problem is more likely realted to Orion or connection.

Thanks for helping!!! I suppose that this is not a very difficult issue but I just can't solve it on my own...

And below is my POST /v2/subscriptions operation:

```
curl -v localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": "A subscription to notify clampPressure change",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "RoboticArm",
        "type": "multiSensor"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "clampPressure"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://host.docker.internal:1028/accumulate"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "clampPressure"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2030-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 1
}
EOF
```

Comment: Please make sure that you have connectivity (from the brokers node to the accumulators node). For example using ping or even better "telnet host.docker.internal 1028" (first make sure the accumulator is running). If this doesn't work, then the notifications won't work

Comment: Thanks for helping! "telnet host.docker.internal 1028" works when the accumulator is running on IPv4 address. I googled and it seemed that IPv6 is not supported for docker desktop for mac... I guess it's more likely for reason 2 since I don't get any logs on Orion of trying to send notifications.

Comment: Good that you have connectivity!   I assume your "self-defined dummy sensor" is "clampPressure" ?  Please add the complete update/creation of the entity to the question and we'll see if we can see anything strange.

Comment: Finally, it works!! Thanks a log for pointing out the right direction!!! There were two problems: 1. Connectivity problem: run the accumulator on IPv4 instead of IPv6    2. Orion: when I made subscription I didn't include `"Fiware-Service: factory"  "Fiware-ServicePath: /demo"`, that was why when I updated entities the Orion didn't show any logs for `httpRequestSend.cpp`

Comment: I'd suggest to provide the solution in a self-answer to the question post. It's better that way than using a coment as it is now ;)